# Album art messed up on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod.app

From time to time the album art on my iPhone 4 becomes completely messed up. In iTunes they are correct, but on the phone they are suddenly mixed up. Album A gets the art from album K, and album C from album G, and by luck album E has the right one... very annoying. I can "fix" it by resyncing everything (don't sync, apply, sync, apply), but I'm getting really tired of that.

Does anyone else experience this? Why does it happen? Anything I can do to fix it more permanently? Does Apple know about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that's caused many people head aches, and also seems to occur on iPhone 3gs models.

For more detail on what fixes have been attempted, you can read this [Apple discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2546022?start=0&tstart=0) on this issue.

There was a discussion thread I read a few months ago (which I can't seem to find) where multiple people reported a success at fixing the issue by doing the following:

1. Unsync all music and playlists on the iPhone
2. Click on the `Apply / Sync` button in iTunes
3. Shutdown / reboot the iPhone
4. Connect to iTunes and once again do a (blank playlist) second sync with iTunes clicking on the `Apply / Sync` button.
5. Add back playlists and re-sync with iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Iphone5 and noticed that my artwork in my music files changed after downloading the latest operating system from Apple in my IPhone. When looking through the music albums not all of them was different but several Artwork covers changed.

I searched the Internet and found no answers for why this is happening. It is correct in ITunes music library but when synced to my phone several of them change. After beating my head awhile trying to correct it in ITunes I found the problem is in setting in the iPhone.

If you go to your phone setting and then in Music, turn off (Group By Album Artist) then all of my art work returned to what it should look like without doing any other steps in my phone or ITunes.