# iOS Album-Art Mismatch Post Sync

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music

Whenever I sync any song to my iPhone, some of the songs / albums display the wrong album art despite having the correct album-art in iTunes. I have had this issue since iOS 8 and all of my devices are up to date on the software side. Check out the examples below:

[image: Incorrect Album-Art]
[image: Incorrect Album-Art even after re-sync]

For example, Ride of the Valkyries shows album-art of ‘A Sky Full of Stars’ when I first synced to the device. After I deleted it from my iPhone and synced the song again, it showed album-art from ‘Songs from The Martian’. For the record, these albums are present in my iTunes library and they display it correctly.
Be advised, this problem only with the album-art, not the song meta-data.

Hardware Info: iTunes 12.3 on Windows with iPhone 5 on iOS 9.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot of sites on the web, also including [StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21357/album-art-messed-up-on-iphone-4), I finally stumbled on this [blog by Kirk McElhearn](http://www.mcelhearn.com/when-ios-devices-replace-artwork-for-some-of-your-albums/). However, it only pointed me the right direction. After trying different methods, the correct solution was not to *disconnect my iPhone from the internet* while I synced, but to **disconnect my PC from the internet** before I started the sync process. Here is the result:

[image: Correct Album-Art by applying the solution]

***And voila!***

It finally showed the correct album-art. However my problem was fixed only for that particular song. I had to delete all the songs that had mismatched album-art and re-sync those songs again. It was a pain-in-the-a**, but the result was worth it (if you are particularly OCD about keeping your music perfect).